# ClentScriptManager .RegisterClientScriptBlock to do js redirect not working server side from button click asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

.net aspx form inside button click

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
        cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"RedirectScript", "window.parent.location = '/sites/service/zones/default.aspx'", true);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "abc", "alert('hi');", true);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "RedirectHome", "window.parent.location = '/sites/service/zones/default.aspx';", true);
    }
```

tried 3 ways nothing works  no error F12 or .net debug server side.  No alert, no redirect happens.

Page is inside an iframe so I use window.parent.location

Answer (score 0):

One should test for existence of NAMED script block before adding...
Consider page life cycle relative to a button click handler...

```cs
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "myscript", script, true);
}
```